# Bash complaints about missing ], while it is there

Tags: bash, test

I have following in a bash script:

```
echo "status: [$status] and message: [$message]"
if [ "${status}" -eq 0 && "$message" = "ERROR" ];
then
        echo "Exit 0";
        exit 0
fi

# status: [0] message: [ERROR]
```

However, it gives below error, and the logic under `then` i.e. `exit 0` never gets executed:

```
line 2: [: missing `]'
```

It seems to be complaining about the missing closing `]`, however, it is there. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The closing `]` is actually not there.

You have:

```
cmd1 with its args && cmd2 with its args
```

Which runs `cmd2` if and only if `cmd1` succeeds.

Where here `cmd1` is the `[` command and `cmd2` is the command whose name is stored in `$message`.

IOW, the first command is

```
[ "${status}" -eq 0
```

Which is missing its closing `]` and the second is:

```
"$message" = "ERROR" ]
```

You want

```
if [ "${status}" -eq 0 ] && [ "$message" = "ERROR" ]; then...
```

In Korn-like shells such as bash, you can also use the `[[...]]` construct in place of the `[` command which understands a sort of micro-language with its very own syntax which as it happens also has a `&&` operator.

```
if [[ $status -eq 0 && $message = ERROR ]]; then
```

But beware that contrary to `[`, that one introduces a command injection vulnerability if the value of `$status` could be under the control of an attacker.

In bash, `[`'s `-eq` operator doesn't have the problem as it only accepts decimal integer numbers and not arbitrary arithmetic expressions like for `[[...]]`'s `-eq`.

```
bash-5.0$ status='a[$(echo>&2 Gotcha)]'
bash-5.0$ [[ $status -eq 0 ]]
Gotcha
```

This kind of problem also affects the `(( status == 0 ))` operator to evaluate C-like arithmetic expressions¹ (also from ksh):

```
bash-5.0$ (( status == 0 ))
Gotcha
```

---

<sup>¹ there's also a `&&` in those arithmetic expressions, but you can't use it here as `((...))` is only for arithmetic stuff so you can't do string comparison in there, you'd need `if (( status == 0 )) && [ "$message" = ERROR ]`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you are using the `[` test construct. This construct does not support boolean operators in the argument in the way the korn-shell/bash-style `[[`-operator does, therefore only one single test may be stated inside `[` ... `]`.

You can either concatenate the two conditions via the [`&&`-chaining at shell level](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/377345) as separate tests, i.e.

```
if [ "${status}" -eq 0 ] && [ "$message" = "ERROR" ];
```

or use the more convenient `[[ ... ]]`-operator instead

```
if [[ "${status}" -eq 0 && "$message" = "ERROR" ]];
```